# how to type props when passing component with svelte:component?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I want to make multi-step form and i need to use `svelte:component` to render step components. I need to pass my custom store in components so i declared prop `store` with `export let store: StepFlowStore` in every component.

```
const store = makeStepFlowStore();
const { step } = store;

const steps: Record<FormSteps, typeof SvelteComponentDev> = {
    [mySteps.first]: AddressForm,
    [mySteps.second]: DetailsForm,
    [mySteps.third]: FinalForm

};
<svelte:component this={steps[$step]} {store} />
```

but i get an error in `steps`

> Property `store` is missing in type `Record<string, any>` but required in type `{ store: StepFlowStore; }`

but i am passing `store` in `svelte:component`. Is there any workaround with explicitly declare prop or is this a flaw in using `svelte:component` with ts and there's nothing I can do?

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to `svelte:component` where you wrote `svelte:element`.

Comment: yes ```svelte:component```, a little got confused

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the types are not reconcilable like this. For component constructors one should use [`ComponentType`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#types-componenttype). (The use of `SvelteComponentDev` suggests that you are using an older version of Svelte, though, as that is no longer exported currently.)

Also, to get the best type checking you can use `satisfies`, that way it will infer a precise type which will cause errors if any required properties are missing.

```js
const steps = {
    [mySteps.first]: AddressForm,
    [mySteps.second]: DetailsForm,
    [mySteps.third]: FinalForm
} satisfies Record<FormSteps, ComponentType>;
```

Comment: Yes, the svelte version is a bit outdated and there is no way to update it yet. Is it possible to make something similar without ComponentType?

Comment: You can probably make it work by declaring the properties explicitly or setting them to `any`, if you use `satisfies` it should still resolve to a precise type: `typeof SvelteComponentTyped<any>` (In later versions `SvelteComponent` can and should be used instead of `SvelteComponentTyped`)